# Have select after like in where condition - mysql

Tags: mysql, where-clause, sql-like

Is it possible to have dynamic a prefix with the *pattern loaded from another query*?

Fix prefix:

```
SELECT NAME FROM TABLE1 WHERE NAME LIKE 'prefix%'
```

Dynamic: ???

```
SELECT NAME FROM TABLE1 WHERE NAME LIKE (SELECT PREFIX FROM PREFIX_TABLE)
```

Comment: Do not use dquotes `"` for string literals, use single quotes `'`.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT /* DISTINCT */ name 
FROM table1 
JOIN prefix_table ON table1.name LIKE CONCAT(prefix_table.prefix, '%')
```